# Generate RadioButtons With Different 'Content'

Tags: c#, c++, .net, wpf, radio-button

I am a C++ developer and currently working on a WPF app where I have to generate 4 radio buttons dynamically and each button will have different title name. I am following MVVM pattern.

```
<Grid Grid.Row="0">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition Height="35" />                
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <RadioButton Grid.Row="0" Content="{Binding RadioBase}" IsChecked="{Binding BaseCheck}" Height="15" Width="80" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
        <Button Grid.Row="1" Content="Refresh Regs" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0" Width="100" Height="25" />
</Grid>
```

Now if you notice my XAMl, I have just One radio button in my `Grid.Row="0"`. Ideally I would want to generate it 4 times and set a binding to its `Content` and `IsChecked` so that I gives me 4 different `Content`.

**ViewModel:**

```
private bool sBaseCheck;
    public bool BaseCheck
    {
        get { return this.sBaseCheck; }
        set
        {
            this.sBaseCheck= value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged("BaseCheck");
        }
    }

private string _RadioBase;
    public string RadioBase
    {
        get
        {
            return _RadioBase;
        }

        set
        {
            _RadioBase= value;
            OnPropertyChanged("RadioBase");
        }
    }
```

I had done this in my C++ application as follows:

```
for(i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    m_registerBase[i] = new ToggleButton(("Base 0x")+String::toHexString(i * 0x40));        
    addAndMakeVisible(m_registerBase[i]);
    m_registerBase[i]->addButtonListener(this);
}
```

If you notice here, It creates it 4 times and has one buttonclick event. It creates Title as follows:

- Button 1 = Base 0x0 (since i = 0 and toHexString converts 0x0 to 0)
- Button 2 = Base 0x40 (since i = 1 and toHexString converts 0x40 to
  40)
- Button 3 = Base 0x80 (since i = 2 and toHexString converts 0x80
  to 80)
- Button 4 = Base 0xc0 (since i = 3 and toHexString converts
  0xc0 to c0)

How can I achieve like this in My WPF application? :) I would appreciate if you guys help me solve this? :)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on yours comment, I created a complete example :

Model:

```
    namespace WpfApplication1
    {
        public class RB
        {
            public bool BaseCheck { get; set; }
            public string RadioBase { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

RBVM:

```
        namespace WpfApplication1
        {
            public class RBVM : INotifyPropertyChanged
            {

                public RBVM()
                {
                    _rb = new RB();
                }

               private RB _rb;
                public RB RB
               {
                   get
                   {
                       return _rb;
                   }
                   set
                   {
                       _rb = value;
                   }
               }

                public bool BaseCheck
                {
                    get
                    {
                        return RB.BaseCheck;
                    }
                    set
                    {
                        RB.BaseCheck = value;
                        RaisePropertyChanged("BaseCheck");
                    }
                }

                public string RadioBase
                {
                    get
                    {
                        return RB.RadioBase;
                    }
                    set
                    {
                        RB.RadioBase = value;
                        RaisePropertyChanged("RadioBase");
                    }
                }








                public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

                                                    #region Methods

            private void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
            {
                PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
                if (handler != null)
                {
                    handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
                }
            }
            #endregion
            }
        }
```

ViewModel:

```
     namespace WpfApplication1
    {
        public class RBViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
        {

            public void AddRb(string content, bool isChk) 
            {
                _rbs.Add(new RBVM() { RadioBase = content, BaseCheck = isChk });
            }


            public void ClearAllValues() {
                foreach (RBVM item in _rbs)
                {
                    item.BaseCheck = false;
                }

            }

            public RBVM GetChecked() {
                foreach (RBVM item in _rbs)
                {
                    if (item.BaseCheck) {
                        return item;
                    }
                }

                return null;

            }


            private ObservableCollection<RBVM> _rbs = new ObservableCollection<RBVM>();


            public ObservableCollection<RBVM> Rbs
           {
               get
               {
                   return _rbs;
               }
               set
               {
                   _rbs = value;
               }
           }



            public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

            #region Methods

            private void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
            {
                PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
                if (handler != null)
                {
                    handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
                }
            }
            #endregion
        }
    }
```

XAML

```
    <Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow1"
            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
            Title="MainWindow1" Height="300" Width="300">

        <Window.DataContext>
            <local:RBViewModel />
        </Window.DataContext>
        <Window.Resources>

            <DataTemplate x:Key="RadioDataTemplate">
                <StackPanel>
                    <RadioButton GroupName="someGroup" Content="{Binding RadioBase}" IsChecked="{Binding BaseCheck}" Height="15" Width="80" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>

        </Window.Resources>

        <Grid x:Name="main">

            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Rbs}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource RadioDataTemplate}">
                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <StackPanel x:Name="radios" />
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            </ItemsControl>

            <Button Width="50" Height="10" x:Name="test" Click="test_Click" ></Button>
        </Grid>

    </Window>
```

XAML Code Behind:

```
          namespace WpfApplication1
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Interaction logic for MainWindow1.xaml
        /// </summary>
        public partial class MainWindow1 : Window
        {
            RBViewModel _viewModel;

            public MainWindow1()
            {
                InitializeComponent();

                _viewModel = (RBViewModel)base.DataContext;


                for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
                {
                    _viewModel.AddRb("a" + i, true);

                }
            }

            private void test_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(_viewModel.GetChecked().RadioBase);
                _viewModel.ClearAllValues();
            }



        }


    }
```

Comment: I am following MVVM pattern So I would want this to happen in ViewModel class. How to do that?

Comment: Please, edit your question and add some relevant code from View and ViewModel.

Comment: Added content and isChecked property in VM class. Although its basic, I need to know how can I achieve it :)

Comment: I hope it will be helpful, put a breakpoint in test_Click to verify that the properties are updated

Comment: Great! I changed test_Click  to clear all radios, and fix viewmodel to clear code.

Comment: Possible to move the code present in .xaml.cs to viewmodel class???? I want to keep all my logic in viewmodel :)

Comment: Ok. The only logic that had is to add items and cleaning. Have already been moved. You meant that?

Comment: All 4 buttons are checked. Lets get rid of the Textbutton. Just have 4 radiobuttons and have a checked property. Ideally i would want only one button to be checked at once. And I should also get to know which button I have clicked.

Comment: Yes, you need set a GroupName... Updated 1 line in XAML

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18564/discussion-between-stonedjesus-and-mate)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to stick to the MVVM pattern you should consider replacing the `Grid` control with an [`ItemsControl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.aspx). You then need two view-models: the child view-model which is the one you have explained about in your question and a parent view-model that contains a collection of the child view models:

```
public ObservableCollection<FPGAViewModel> Children { get; set; }

    public ParentViewModel()
    {
        Children = new ObservableCollection<FPGAViewModel>();
        Children.Add(new FPGAViewModel() { RadioBase = "Base 0x0" });
        Children.Add(new FPGAViewModel() { RadioBase = "Base 0x40" });
        Children.Add(new FPGAViewModel() { RadioBase = "Base 0x80" });
        Children.Add(new FPGAViewModel() { RadioBase = "Base 0xc0" });
    }
```

If you want to be able to dynamically add and remove child items you should use a collection based on `ObservableCollection<T>` but it seems that you want to stick to exactly four child items.

The `ItemsControl` can generate items based on a template (`ItemTemplate`) for each item in the `ItemsSource`. These items will be placed in the `ItemsPanel` which by default is a `StackPanel`. Stacking the radio buttons on top of each is probably what you want.

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical"
                    IsItemsHost="True" />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <RadioButton Content="{Binding RadioBase}" Margin="0,10,0,0" IsChecked="{Binding BaseCheck}" Height="15" Width="80" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Note that the `DataContext` of the `ItemsControl` should be set to an instance of `ParentViewModel`. In MVVM this is done by binding the view containing the `ItemsControl` to the parent view-model. When `ItemsControl` generates child items each `RadioButton` will have a `DataContext` bound to each `ChildViewModel` instance and the bindings in the `RadioButton` will bind to that view-model.

Comment: @Matrin Liversage: Is this what you were tying to tell? :)

Comment: How about the IsChecked??? How will I Get to know which radiobutton I have clicked??? Lets say make a property called ID and set it to each radiobutton. Is that right?

Comment: @StonedJesus: I was trying to provide a simple answer that demonstrated a basic pattern in WPF. Your edits have made the answer somewhat more complex but as long as the edits make sense to you I guess it improves the answer. I don't see why you need to specify the `ItemsPanel` because the default is a vertical `StackPanel`. When a `RadioButton` is checked the `BaseCheck` property in the corresponding `FPGAViewModel` is set to `true`. You can something like LINQ to get the checked instance: `Children.FirstOrDefault(vm => vm.BaseCheck)`.

Comment: I have not worked on LINQ. Can you elaborate more on it pls? A sample code to get which buton is checked :)

Comment: @StonedJesus: You can use a for loop instead if you prefer. I already provided you with a LINQ expression but let me elaborate: `var checkedFpgaViewModel = Children.FirstOrDefault(vm => vm.BaseCheck);`. It searches the `Children` collection for the first view-model where `BaseCheck` is true. If no view-model satisfies this criteria `null` is returned.

Comment: Well `for` loop would be good. All radiobuttons are getting checked. Ideally I would want only one radiobutton to be checked even if i click all 4. How can that be achieved? PLus I got your point of using LINQ method. Can you update the answer with the code related to for loop?

Answer (score 0):

```
for(i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    m_registerBase[i] = new RadioButton();        
    m_registerBase[i].IsChecked=true;
    //Sets the Binding programmatcially
    m_registerBase[i].SetBinding(RadioButton.Content, "MyContent");
}
```

[The RadioButton Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.radiobutton.aspx)

[SetBinding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.setbinding.aspx)

Comment: @Codelgnoto:I am following MVVM pattern So I would want this to happen in ViewModel class. How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Yopu can achieve dynamic generation of grouped `RadioBox`es using following `XAML` & `Binding`

**XAML:**

```
<ListBox SelectionMode="Single"
         SelectedValue="{Binding CurrentRadioDescription}"
         SelectedValuePath="Description"
         ItemsSource="{Binding RadioBoxModelList}" 
    Focusable="True"
    KeyboardNavigation.IsTabStop="True"          
    VerticalAlignment="Center"
    BorderBrush="Transparent"
    BorderThickness="0"
    Background="Transparent" >
<ListBox.Resources>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" 
    Color="Transparent"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}" 
    Color="Transparent"/> 
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlDarkBrushKey}" 
    Color="Transparent"/> 
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.InactiveBorderBrushKey}" 
    Color="Transparent"/> 
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlDarkDarkBrushKey}" 
    Color="Transparent"/> 
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlLightBrushKey}" 
    Color="Transparent"/> 
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlLightLightBrushKey}" 
    Color="Transparent"/> 
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.WindowBrushKey}" 
    Color="Transparent"/>
</ListBox.Resources>
<ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
    <StackPanel 
        Orientation="Horizontal"
        Background="Transparent"/>
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemsPanel>
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
    <RadioButton 
          MinWidth="80"
                  Background="Transparent"
          IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsSelected, 
                  RelativeSource={RelativeSource 
                    AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}},
                  Mode=TwoWay}"
         Content="{Binding Description, Mode=OneWay}" 
         Margin="-1"/>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

**C#**

```
public class RadioBoxModel : INotifyPropertyChanged { 
      //Raise property changed notifications in Setters below.
      public bool IsChecked { get; set; } 
      public string Description { get; set; }
}
```